# How to write line by line in an output file without replacing the old line

Tags: java

I have a file with lines as below

```
ar1 = [[Hello how are you], [I am doing fine] , [How about you] , [What do you do]]
ar2 = [[hey], [how are you] , [whats up] , [nothing much]]

List<List<String>> ar1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<List<String>> ar2 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

for (int i = 0; i < ar1.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < ar2.size(); j++) {
                     if(ar1.get(i).get(0).equalsIgnoreCase(ar2.get(j).get(0)) ){
                         PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/output.txt"));
                         out.println(ar1.get(i));
                         out.println(ar2.get(j))
                         out.flush();
                     }
                }
            }
```

The output of this file is printing only  "What do you do" and "nothing much" .. How can i print all the lines in the output file.

```
The output should be 
Hello how are you 
hey 
I am doing fine  
how are you and so on
```

Comment: you should to fix your code put your String between " "

Comment: ar1 = [[Hello how are you], [I am doing fine] , [How about you] , [What do you do]]
    ar2 = [[hey], [how are you] , [whats up] , [nothing much]]

Answer (score 3):

Simply move your `PrintStream` declaration outside the loops.

Indeed `new FileOutputStream(File)` will start writing from the beginning of your file since the append mode is disabled in this case such that you override the previous content of your file. You may be interested in the other constructor `new FileOutputStream(File, boolean)` if you want to always append the new content at the end of your file.

I believe that what you want to achieve is more something like this:

```
List<List<String>> ar1 = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList("Hello how are you"),
    Arrays.asList("I am doing fine"),
    Arrays.asList("How about you"),
    Arrays.asList("What do you do")
);
List<List<String>> ar2 = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList("hey"),
    Arrays.asList("how are you"),
    Arrays.asList("whats up"),
    Arrays.asList("nothing much")
);
try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/output.txt"))) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ar1.size() || i < ar2.size(); i++) {
        if (i < ar1.size() && !ar1.get(i).isEmpty()) {
            out.println(ar1.get(i).get(0));
        }
        if (i < ar2.size() && !ar2.get(i).isEmpty()) {
            out.println(ar2.get(i).get(0));
        }
        out.flush();
    }            
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello how are you
hey
I am doing fine
how are you
How about you
whats up
What do you do
nothing much
```

**NB:** You should have a `List` of `String` instead of a `List` of `List` of `String`

Comment: I moved the print stream outside the loop.. Now the output is returned in list<String> . I want the output line by line in a string

Comment: Using println as you do is the right approach, what's wrong?

Comment: what do you have a List of List of String? Why not simply a list of String?

Comment: That's because i have to match with something . So i cannot do it with just List of string

Comment: I tried the above method , its not giving me the output .

Comment: I've tested it, it works. show me how your List are created

Comment: [[hello, how, are, you] [hey]] and so on

Comment: it is not helping much, add in your question the code that you use to create your Lists. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code should look like this

```
ar1 = [[Hello how are you], [I am doing fine] , [How about you] , [What do you do]]
ar2 = [[hey], [how are you] , [whats up] , [nothing much]]

List<List<String>> ar1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<List<String>> ar2 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
String strOutput = "";
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");

for (int i = 0; i < ar1.size(); i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < ar2.size(); j++) {
          if(ar1.get(i).get(0).equalsIgnoreCase(ar2.get(j).get(0)) ){
                 if (i > 0 || j > 0) {
                      strOutput += newline;
                 }
                 strOutput += ar1.get(i);
                 strOutput += newline;
                 strOutput += ar2.get(j);
           }
     }
}

PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/output.txt"));
out.println(strOutput);
out.flush();
```

Comment: This is still returning returning the output as below :
[The output should be ]
[Hello how are you ]
[hey ]
[I am doing fine  ]
how are you and so on